# How to integrate Youtube video view integration without YoutubeBaseActivity | Android

Tags: android, youtube

I am integrating Youtube videoview in my app and it is working fine when i am using YoutubeBaseActivity as a parent class.

But my requirement is to use Appcompact activity as a parent activity.

How can i do that?

Suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to take another activity which extends the youtube base activity ...and intialize the things in that activtiy....then extend that activity  where you need to implement the functionality

Answer (score 0):

Add [YouTubePlayerFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) to your Activity